# If I format a machine that's running Ubuntu and install Windows, will the physical network address change?

Tags: formatting, network-adapter, mac-address

My ISP binds the access to the physical address of my computer.

I bought a new one yesterday and I had to call them to tell them the new physical address.

Will it change if I format the computer and install Windows?

I know the question is very dumb, but I just want to make sure. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, most ISPs bind the MAC address of your network interface (ethernet port in this case most probably) to stop more than one machine to be added to their network per customer. If you format the hard drive, the MAC address for the network interface will not change, that is coded into the interface when it is manufactured.

Comment: I thought so, but had to make sure first. Thank you Ptier! :)